# Transform sparse double return of a sparse matrix in a double value

Tags: matlab, matrix, casting, double, sparse-matrix

In Matlab, how to transform a sparse double(1,1) in just a double value. like this

```
S = sparse(1234567)

S = (1,1)        1234567
```

in this a double value

```
S = 1234567
```

I need because I'm counting a sparse matrix and doing this, sum == a value return occurence of a x value, but in a sparse double context.

Comment: [`full`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/full.html)

Comment: Ok, updated now I think its possible to understand the question.

Comment: Nice tip @excaza put in the answer to win a point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's just use the function full().

A = full(S) converts a sparse matrix S to full storage organization, such that issparse(A) returns logical 0 (false). If S is a full matrix, then A is identical to S.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/full.html

```
full(S)

S = 1234567
```